# Excel VBA - Split a cell into 1000 pieces and copy them into different cells

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if there is a way to split a cell with for example 6000 words into 1000 word pieces. So for example,  1000 words in cell C1, then the next 1000 words in C2 and so on.

Here is the code I have so far.

The output of that code (Cell C1) should be split, with C6 with 1000 words, C7 with 1000 words and so on until no more words are available.

Thank you in advance!

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Dim dStr As String, aCell As Range
Dim cet, i As Long

Sub countWords()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim iniWords As Long, lWords As Long
Dim wK As Worksheet
On Error GoTo Err

Set wK = ActiveSheet

dStr = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(wK.Range("A1:A" & wK.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value), " ")
'iniWords = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wK.Range("A1:A" & wK.Rows.Count))
cet = Split(dStr, " ")
iniWords = UBound(cet)

wK.Range("A1:A" & wK.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

'lWords = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wK.Range("A1:A" & wK.Rows.Count))

dStr = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(wK.Range("A1:A" & wK.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value), " ")
cet = Split(dStr, " ")

dStr = ""
For i = LBound(cet) To UBound(cet)
    If Trim(cet(i)) <> "" And InStr(dStr, Trim(cet(i))) = 0 Then
        dStr = Trim(dStr) & " " & Trim(cet(i))
    End If
Next i
dStr = Trim(dStr)

cet = Split(dStr, " ")
lWords = UBound(cet)
wK.Range("C1") = dStr

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Words: " & iniWords & vbNewLine & _
        "Removed duplicates " & iniWords - lWords & vbNewLine & _
        "Remaining Words " & lWords




Exit Sub

Err:
    MsgBox "There is no data in row A"


End Sub
```

Comment: and what's wrong with your code?

Comment: What does your code so far achieve vs. what you want it to achieve? i.e. what aspect of this is the tricky bit for you?

Comment: It's nothing wring with the code. Right now the tool takes row A and collects all words into one cell (into Cell C1). But I don't know how splitt Cell C1 into cells with 1000 words.

The output of that code (Cell C1) should be splited to C6 with 1000 words, C7 with 1000 words and so on until no more words are available.

Comment: @Chris Hello, if you want to count the number of characters then use `Left`, `Mid`, or `Right`, see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/y050k1wb(v=vs.90).aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Const NWORDS As Long = 100 '<--| it's the number of words you want each cell to be written with. change it to your needs

    Dim strng As String
    Dim rowOffset As Long

    With Range("C1")
        strng = .Value
        rowOffset = 5 '<--| point to C7 at the first iteration
        Do
            strng = Replace(strng, " ", "|", , NWORDS) '<--| "mark" the first NWORDS with a different separator (be sure pipe ("|") is not a character you can have in your words)
            .Offset(rowOffset).Value = Replace(Left(strng, InStrRev(strng, "|") - 1), "|", " ") '<--| write first NWORDS words in current 'rowoffset' cell
            strng = Right(strng, Len(strng) - InStrRev(strng, "|"))
            rowOffset = rowOffset + 1 '<--| update row offset
        Loop While UBound(Split(strng, " ")) > NWORDS - 1
        .Offset(rowOffset).Value = strng
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Chris, did you get  through it?

Comment: @Chris, any chance to get feedback from you?

Comment: I'm sorry 5 years later. Yes it worked.